# My "next" button links was okay but my build crash

Tags: xcode4.5

I attached the functions to the buttons and when I run the app, it works just fine, but when I click the button, my app stop running and i was prompt back to the xcode.

Did I do something wrong?

Im trying to make a "next function" using IBAction that when i click the button it will move my page into another app page called "about us".
I used some guide from youtube and came up with the coding as followed;

**Viewcontroller.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{}
-(IBAction)next;
```

**Viewcontroller.m**

```
@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)next;
{
    About_Us *AU = [[About_Us alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:AU animated:NO completion:NO];
}
```

*There was a green text highlighted over* the code below, saying "`Thread 1:breakpoint 3.1 4.1`"

```
About_Us *AU = [[About_Us alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

Recently the guide im using might be outdated as the version for xcode has been upgraded, it would be nice if i can have some assistance with it.

Comment: Is there an error message? Do you have a breakpoint set?

Comment: This is hard to understand. Can you rephrase your question/give us more detail?